# Open Search Server v1.4 select query special characters

Tags: search-engine, opensearch

We're using Open Search Server v1.4.  When the user enters a search for the text "Refrigerator temperature chart (5" we create a URL something like

```
http://10.192.16.160:8080/services/rest/select/search/<indexname/json?login=<login>&key=<apikey>template=search&query=Refrigerator%20temperature%20chart%20%285&start=0&rows=1000&filter=fileType%3afile&lang=ENGLISH
```

This fails with ...

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   com.jaeksoft.searchlib.SearchLibException:
>   com.jaeksoft.searchlib.query.ParseException:
>   org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse
>   'content:(Refrigerator temperature chart (5) OR content:("Refrigerator
>   temperature chart (5") OR

So adding an escape character %5C before the open bracket fixes this query like so...

```
http://10.192.16.160:8080/services/rest/select/search/<indexname/json?login=<login>&key=<apikey>template=search&query=Refrigerator%20temperature%20chart%20%5C%285&start=0&rows=1000&filter=fileType%3afile&lang=ENGLISH
```

Can someone point me to some documentation that lists all the special characters that can be used in an Open Search select query that need to be escaped when entered as part of the search string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, characters listed in section "Escaping Special Characters" in the page you linked also need to be escaped in OpenSearchServer.

We recently released a fix allowing to escape those characters in query of type `Search (field)` for `Searched fields` configured with a `pattern` mode.

Previously escaping of characters was only available in query of type `Search (pattern)`.
(more information of these two kind of queries here: http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/tutorials/functionalities.html#two-kinds-of-queries)

Regards,

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

I believe Open Search Server is based on Lucene.  The query syntax for the Lucene engine is described here...

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

> Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query
>   syntax. The current list special characters are
>
> + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
>
> To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example
>   to search for (1+1):2 use the query:
>
> \(1\+1\)\:2

Comment: I found that if I have a field with text "#3123" if I search for the # symbol, it does not work.  why would that be?